Finding a smooth surface with boundary as a Jordan curve in a simply connected domain
Consider the following:
For any smooth Jordan curve $\gamma\subset D$, where $D$ is simply connected, we can find a smooth surface $\Sigma \subset D$ such that $\partial\Sigma = \gamma$.
I am curious about the validity of the statement and how could one possibly go about proving it with more rigour rather than intuition. This was used in a proof that if the vector field is irrotational and the domain is simply connected then it is integrable. Just stating it felt very hand-wavy
Thank you for any suggestions or ideas!

What is $D$, aside from simply connected? It sounds like it's a region in $\Bbb R^3$.  I believe you also want $\Sigma$ to be an orientable surface (with boundary) if you're wanting to apply Stokes's Theorem. At any rate, you might read about the Seifert surface of a knot.

@TedShifrin exactly what I meant, I should have said it:) Thank you!
